Georeferenced images from a grid
I have a layer with the attributes height, width, x, y, vertex_ind and a path pointing to a non-georeferenced jpg image.
I know how to use the x,y coordinates of each vertex to translate the angles of the image, then reproject the file to get a tif.
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 985722.224 6281490.969 -gcp 2795 0 990947.069 6282185.729 -gcp 2795 2998 991778.729 6276821.682 "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p401.jpg" "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p401_trans.jpg"

gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=None -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:2154 "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p401_trans.jpg" "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p401_reproj.tif"

I now want to make a script to automate this because my layer points to hundreds of non-georeferenced images.
I started writing this script but it doesn't work.
import os
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    path = feature["path"]
    height = feature["height"]
    width = feature["width"]
    x = feature["x"]
    y = feature["y"]

    output_path = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + "_trans.jpg"
    gdal_translate_command = (
        f"gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 {x} {y} -gcp {width} 0 {x} {y} -gcp {width} {height} {x} {y}"
        f"{path} {output_path}"
    )

    print(f"Exécution de gdal_translate : {gdal_translate_command}")
    if os.system(gdal_translate_command) != 0:
        print(f"Erreur lors de gdal_translate pour : {path}")
        continue

    warp_path = os.path.splitext(output_path)[0] + "_reproj.tif"
    gdal_warp_command = (
        f"gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=NONE -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:2154 "
        f"-tps {output_path} {warp_path}"
    )

    print(f"Exécution de gdalwarp : {gdal_warp_command}")
    if os.system(gdal_warp_command) == 0:
        print(f"Fichier TIFF reprojeté créé avec succès : {warp_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Erreur lors de gdalwarp pour : {output_path}")

The error message :
exec(compile(Path('C:/Users/p/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpyc_gqyrn').read_text(), 'Sans titre 11', 'exec'))
Exécution de gdalwarp : gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=NONE -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:2154 -tps D:\__SIG__\nouvel_essai\2003_mission_768\a03_m768_p709_trans.tif D:\__SIG__\nouvel_essai\2003_mission_768\a03_m768_p709_trans_reproj.tif
Erreur lors de gdalwarp pour : D:\__SIG__\nouvel_essai\2003_mission_768\a03_m768_p709_trans.tif

Do you have any idea?

You seem to be setting all the gcps to the same x,y

You add a parameter in your python script. -tps is not in your working example in command line.  Maybe you don't use it as expected?

It 's ok:
import os

# couche sommets extraits des dalles
layer = iface.activeLayer()
if not layer:
    raise Exception("Aucune couche active trouvée.")

# liste des attributs utiles
required_fields = ["path", "vertex_ind", "x", "y", "width", "height"]
missing_fields = [field for field in required_fields if field not in [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]]
if missing_fields:
    raise Exception(f"pb : {', '.join(missing_fields)}")

# Regroupement des angles par image
images_gcp = {}
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    path = feature["path"]
    vertex_ind = feature["vertex_ind"]
    x = feature["x"]
    y = feature["y"]
    output_width = feature["width"]
    output_height = feature["height"]

    # vérifi des paths
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print(f"Fichier non trouvé pour le chemin spécifié dans la couche : {path}")
        continue

    if path not in images_gcp:
        images_gcp[path] = []

    # décalage des angles
    if vertex_ind == 1:
        images_gcp[path].append((0, 0, x, y))
    elif vertex_ind == 2:
        images_gcp[path].append((output_width, 0, x, y))
    elif vertex_ind == 3:
        images_gcp[path].append((output_width, output_height, x, y))
    elif vertex_ind == 4:
        images_gcp[path].append((0, output_height, x, y))


# utilisation de fichier temporaire
temp_dir = os.path.join(os.environ.get("TEMP", "/tmp"))

# traitement des images
for path, gcps in images_gcp.items():
    # Vérifier que les 4 GCPs sont présents
    if len(gcps) != 4:
        print(f"Image ignorée (4 GCPs requis) : {path}")
        continue

    # chemin de sortie fichier tif temporaire
    base_name = os.path.basename(path)
    translated_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{os.path.splitext(base_name)[0]}_translated.tif")
    warped_path = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + "_georef.tif"

    # commande gdal_translate
    gdal_translate_command = f"gdal_translate -of GTiff "
    for gcp in gcps:
        gdal_translate_command += f"-gcp {gcp[0]} {gcp[1]} {gcp[2]} {gcp[3]} "
    gdal_translate_command += f"\"{path}\" \"{translated_path}\""

    # excution gdal_translate
    print(f"Exécution de : {gdal_translate_command}")
    result = os.system(gdal_translate_command)
    if result != 0:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la création du fichier intermédiaire pour : {path}")
        continue

    # commande gdalwarp
    gdalwarp_command = (
        f"gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=None -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:2154 "
        f"\"{translated_path}\" \"{warped_path}\""
    )

    # excution gdalwarp
    print(f"Exécution de : {gdalwarp_command}")
    result = os.system(gdalwarp_command)
    if result == 0:
        print(f"Fichier géoréférencé créé avec succès : {warped_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la création du fichier géoréférencé pour : {path}")

